# Saving multiple data.table as new worksheets in existent .xlsx file

Tags: r, shiny, xlconnect

in an R Shiny-App I'm trying to make a download handler save several data.tables - which are stored as reactive values - in an existent .xlsx file, each in a single new worksheet, using XLConnect and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Thank you for your help. 
Example:

```
output$saveDTs <- downloadHandler(
    filename = paste0( codeNr, "file_.xlsx"),
    content = function( file ) {
      if ( (is.null(values$dt1)) && (is.null(values$dt2)) & (is.null(values$dt3)) ) { return() }

      fname <- paste0(file, ".xlsx")
      wb <- loadWorkbook( fname, create = TRUE)

      if(!is.null(values$dt1 ) ){ 
        dt1 <- values$dt1
        createSheet( wb, "DT1" )
        writeWorksheet( wb, dt1, sheet = "DT1") 
      }
      if(!is.null(values$dt2 ) ){ 
        dt2 <- values$dt2
        createSheet( wb, "DT2" )
        writeWorksheet( wb, dt2, sheet = "LDT2") 
      }
      if(!is.null(values$dt3 ) ){ 
        dt3 <- values$dt3
        createSheet( wb, "DT3" )
        writeWorksheet( wb, dt3, sheet = "DT3") 
      }
      saveWorkbook(wb)
      file.rename( fname, file )
    }
  )
```

Comment: what type of error message are you seeing?

Comment: The prompt to save the file appears, I click on Ok but nothing is saved. No error in R studio or shiny app.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the correct directory? That does not look like an unambiguous file location.